# Using jQuery's ajax get request with parameters, returning page content

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, get, request

I'm trying to use jQuery's get function to call my php script. The php script returns a variable containing the built template of the main content of my page minus my static header/footer.

I would like to use the returned content to replace the "old" page content without the page reloading. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to where I'm going wrong here? My code is as follows...

jQuery:

```
function getData(time, type) {
     $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "getData.php",
            data: "time=" + time + "&type=" + type,
            success: function(data){
               $('#pageContent').fadeOut("slow");
               $('#pageContent').html(data);
               $('#pageContent').fadeIn("slow");
     }
    });
    return false;
}
```

getData.php(paraphrased):

```
    ....

    $time = empty($_GET['time']) ? '' : $_GET['time'];
    $type = empty($_GET['type']) ? '' : $_GET['type'];
    echo getData($time, $type);

    function getData($time, $type)
    ......
        .....
            $tmpl = new Template();
            $tmpl->time= $time;
            $tmpl->type = $type;
            $builtpage = $tmpl->build('index.tmpl');
            return $builtpage;
        .....
    ......
```

jQuery function call:

```
<a href="#" onclick="getData('<?php print $tmpl->time; ?>', 'Orange')">Orange</a>
<a href="#" onclick="getData('<?php print $tmpl->time; ?>', 'Apple')">Apple</a>
<a href="#" onclick="getData('<?php print $tmpl->time; ?>', 'Banana')">Banana</a>
```

When I click any link, the ajax seems to run fine, and the page does refuse to reload, but the content still remains unchanged... Anyone happen to know what's up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First in the `success` function, check to make sure that you are receiving what you are looking for:

```
success: function(data){
  alert(data);
}
```

Also in the php file, try putting this on top of the script:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html");
```

And try modifying your code like:

```
success: function(data){
  $('#pageContent').html(''); // remove what was before
  $('#pageContent').fadeOut("slow");
  $('#pageContent').html(data);
  $('#pageContent').fadeIn("slow");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Ajax will not run fine:

```
<a href="#" onclick="getData("<?php print $tmpl->time; ?>", "Orange")">Orange</a>
                             ^
                             End of attribute value here
```

Use a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) and nest your quotes correctly (by switching between `"` and `'` or using entities).

Comment: Appreciate it, but these were just careless typos as I'm at work and don't have the code readily in front of me

Comment: *facepalm* — debugging code which is *like* some other code which doesn't work is always so much fun.